# @ObservableObject being updated but not refreshing the View Body

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass down Game data from a main view to child cells in a ForEach. This seems to work and the observable object is updating but the view itself doesn't seem to update. Below is the main GameView where we create the cells

```
struct GameView: View {
@State var money: Float! = 0.0
@ObservedObject var moneyMakers: MoneyMakerModel
@State var companyName: String! = "Alpaca Inc."
@State var gameMoney: Float = SavedGame.shared.money

    @Environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight) var minRowHeight
    
    init() {
        self.moneyMakers = MoneyMakerModel.shared
        GameManager.GAME_VIEW = self
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                Text("$\(gameMoney)")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Text("Alpaca Inc.")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .font(Font.headline)
                Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            VStack {
                ForEach(moneyMakers.moneyMakers) { moneyMaker in
                    MoneyMakerCell(moneyMaker: moneyMaker)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing])
                }
                .frame(minHeight: minRowHeight * CGFloat(STARTING_MONEY_MAKERS.count))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am using a model to pass through an Observable object shown below

```
class MoneyMakerModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var moneyMakers: \[MoneyMaker\] = SavedGame.shared.moneyMakers

    public static let shared = MoneyMakerModel()
    private init(){}

}
```

and in my cell, I am consuming this like so. If I put a breakpoint in the code at "@observedObject" below, I can see that it is called when the data in the MoneyMakerModel is updated, but still no run on the body of the MoneyMakerCellView.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MoneyMakerCell: View {
@State var name: String! = "Placeholder"
@State var manager: Bool! = false
@State var incomeManagerRate: Float! = 0.0

    @State var level: Int! = 0
    @State var updateLevel: Int! = 0
    @State var maxUpdateLevel: Int! = 0
    
    @ObservedObject var moneyMaker: MoneyMaker // <--- This runs on breakpoint but no update below
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.opacity(0.4)
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(name)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    Button("Upgrade") {
                        do {
                            try GameManager.upgradeMoneyMaker(moneyMaker: moneyMaker)
                        } catch (let error) {
                            print("ERROR: \(error)")
                            // TODO: SHOW ERROR MESSAGE
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                ProgressView("Upgrade \(self.moneyMaker.updateLevel)/\(moneyMaker.maxUpdateLevel)", value: (Float(self.moneyMaker.updateLevel)), total: 100)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                Spacer()
                
                if !manager {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("$\(incomeManagerRate)")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        Button("Hire Manager") {
                            do {
                                try GameManager.upgradeMoneyMaker(moneyMaker: moneyMaker)
                            } catch (let error) {
                                print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'd really love some help with this as I've been going nuts over it the past two days. I think I am misunderstanding how Observed Objects are working and would love to understand and get over this hump.

I tried switching to StateObject and @State but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the MoneyMakerCell. Im going to provide some basic code that hopefully hopes you solve your problem. This is how I created my Observable Object.

```
class MoneyMakerModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var moneyMakers: [String] = ["A", "B", "C"] // Your custom Object
}
```

This is where I would init my Observable Object and would pass the moneyMakerModel as an Environment Object into my MoneyMakerCell.

```
struct GameView: View {
    @StateObject var moneyMakerModel = MoneyMakerModel() //Init
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //Just to check if its getting updated
            ForEach(moneyMakerModel.moneyMakers, id: \.self) { moneyMaker in
                Text(moneyMaker)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.green)
            }
            
            ForEach(moneyMakerModel.moneyMakers, id: \.self) { moneyMaker in
                MoneyMakerCell(moneyMaker: moneyMaker)
                    .environmentObject(moneyMakerModel) // <-- HERE
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .background(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my MoneyMakerCell looks like.

```
struct MoneyMakerCell: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var moneyMakerModel: MoneyMakerModel
    
    @State var moneyMaker: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(moneyMaker)
            .onTapGesture {
                if let moneyMakerIndex = moneyMakerModel.moneyMakers.firstIndex(where: { $0 == moneyMaker }) {
                    moneyMaker = String(Int.random(in: 0 ... 100))
                    
                    $moneyMakerModel.moneyMakers[moneyMakerIndex].wrappedValue = moneyMaker
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This is a simple example only using strings in your case you're using a custom object. Copy and paste it in Xcode to see how it works, hopefully this helps you with your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**General**

Your solution has a couple of issues. But first, I would recommend to read and work through introductional tutorials. Specifically learn what the difference and the use case of @State, `@ObservedObject` and `@StateObject` is. Also, learn what the key constraints of an ObservableObject's published properties are.

**Why are you not seeing changes**

So, the main issue in your code is, that you are using an ObservableObject whose published property has reference semantic. That means, the ObservableObject only sends change events when that *reference value* will change – but not *when any properties of that reference will change*.
While there are workarounds to come over this, it is generally recommended to keep this simple and exclusively use types with *value semantic* (Swift structs, primitive types, etc.) for your published properties.

So, this above is the reason why you don't receive change notifications in your view - there aren't any.

**Binding a Model to a View**

The other issue has to do how you provide the model. Basically, when any view itself is creating the model, you should use the `@StateObject` property wrapper to declare that the life time of the model is bound to the life time of the *underlying* view (not the SwiftUI View!). Notice, that in this case the view *owns* the model, and no one can see the model (but may see side effects). The model is private to the view.

When the view model is defined outside the view and has different lifetime than the view, you should use the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper to bind the model to the view. The idiomatic approach is to have a parent view set the model in the child view. In your code you are using the View's initialiser to set the model.

**What is a UIView anyway?**

Here, I fear there is a misconception what a SwiftUI's view initialiser is and what a SwiftUI view actually is all about. It's not what you might think it is. SwiftUI is a declarative UI framework. Think of a SwiftUI View as a *function*, where you create and modify the underlying actual view (which renders the pixels). So, SwiftUI views are a means to compose those creation and mutation functions. The initialiser of a SwiftUI view may act to setup those parameters of that create/modifier function (actually, the SwiftUI implementation is slightly more complex which uses closures which actually will be called only once during initialisation of the underlying view).

What it means in your code: when ever you make changes to your view you create this SwiftUI view and the model will be set – every time. Actually, you only need it set it *once*, when you create the underlying view (using the same SwiftUI view). So, even your code seems not to be harmful, you should avoid using confusing code and go for the idiomatic approach.

**Uhm ...**

This statement

```
        GameManager.GAME_VIEW = self
```

definitely is a sign, that you need to understand what SwiftUI views actually are. I would bet, that what ever you are trying to accomplish is at least very troublesome, and probably won't work or has undesired side effects which you are not aware yet.

**OK, what to do next?**

I would recommend start with refactoring your "App State". Note that AppState is not a "Model", it's simply plain data without logic. Your Model will add logic and may modify the app state internally. Sure enough, there should be only one model that changes your app state. Your logic will be invoked caused by events and methods called on your model. The model then publishes the new published value.

Define your App State by means of using types with value semantics (structs, enums). Simply don't use classes for App State.

Also, don't use shared globals with mutable state! NEVER EVAR!

Next, use an idiomatic approach to define your SwiftUI Views using either `@StateObject` or `@ObservableObject` where you bind the model which publishes values with value semantic.

Do not use the SwiftUI Environment to pass through view state, instead in some root view of your SwiftUI View hierarchy, extract the published properties and pass them down to the child views. That way, child view don't need to know anything from Model – they just get strings, numbers etc. which they render.

I would recommend to use the environment for dependencies and configurations, not for passing down models objects. It's possible yes, but from a design perspective it causes undesired coupling.

I think, this was a lot of things. Now, it's your turn, happy coding!